# React form triggers button onClick with every input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a form which has two inputs and a button. When you click the button, the input fields are used to update the state and then show an alert with the information saved in the state. Currently, I have the inputs changing the state but its calling the alert function every time a letter is added to the input...

```
handleSubmit= (e) =>{
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state, null, '  '));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

            <label>
              Username:
              <input
              type="text"
              name="username"
              placeholder="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
            />
            </label>
            <label>
              Password:
              <input
              type="text"
              name="password"
              placeholder="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
            />
            </label>

            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
            <p>{this.state.token}</p>
          <WelcomeStory></WelcomeStory>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Thank you, this is my first front end framework so it has been a big learning curve.

Comment: Remove parentheses from this.handleSubmit() so it's not called right away.

Comment: this will fix your issue : 
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button> 
or <button onClick={ () => this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>

Comment: @ymaghzaz if you do the second option, you'll want to make sure to pass the event object along

Comment: @azium yeah you are right , but i thinks that the event object will not be needed for this context.

Comment: @Josef your solution worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want the function being called right away, but rather only when the button is clicked. `onClick` is an event listener waiting for the button to be clicked before calling `this.handleSubmit`. By having parenthesis, it will call the `handleSubmit` function as soon as the component is rendered. There are similar questions on SO where people go into it at greater detail if you would like to understand when you should use parenthesis and when you shouldn't: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178136/when-to-call-function-vs-function-in-react-onclick).

```
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
```