# Arrow Functions in React/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I want to understand How the below code works and what is the difference between the two and how it gets rendered in react application

```
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-danger"
            onClick={() => onTestClick(test)}>
            Test
          </button>


          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-danger"
            onClick={onTestClick(test)}>
            Test
          </button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to call function vs function() in react onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178136/when-to-call-function-vs-function-in-react-onclick)

Comment: You can take a look at this too [Correct use of arrow functions in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it clear, this is **not** `React-specific behavior`; it is a part of how functions work in `JavaScript`. Generally, if you refer to a method without `()` after it, such as `onClick={this.handleClick}​`, you should `bind` that method.

If calling bind annoys you, there are two ways you can get around this. If you are using the experimental `public class fields syntax`, you can use class fields to correctly bind callbacks.

If you aren’t using class fields syntax, you can use an `arrow function in the callback`.

The problem with `arrow function  syntax` is that a different callback is created each time the `button` renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a `prop` to lower components, those components might do an extra `re-rendering`. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

You can read more about this on their documentation here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html